# Using member shared_ptr from a member callback function running in different thread (ROS topic subscription)

Tags: c++, callback, thread-safety, smart-pointers, ros

I am not completely sure how to best title this question since I am not completely sure what the nature of the problem actually is (I guess "how fix segfault" is not a good title).

The situation is, I have written this code:

```
template <typename T> class LatchedSubscriber {
private:
  ros::Subscriber sub;
  std::shared_ptr<T> last_received_msg;
  std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> mutex;
  int test;

  void callback(T msg) {
    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> thread_local_mutex = mutex;
    std::shared_ptr<T> thread_local_msg = last_received_msg;

    if (!thread_local_mutex) {
      ROS_INFO("Mutex pointer is null in callback");
    }
    if (!thread_local_msg) {
      ROS_INFO("lrm: pointer is null in callback");
    }
    ROS_INFO("Test is %d", test);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(*thread_local_mutex);

    *thread_local_msg = msg;
  }

public:
  LatchedSubscriber() {
    last_received_msg = std::make_shared<T>();
    mutex = std::make_shared<std::mutex>();
    test = 42;

    if (!mutex) {
      ROS_INFO("Mutex pointer is null in constructor");
    }
    else {
      ROS_INFO("Mutex pointer is not null in constructor");
    }

    
  }

  void start(ros::NodeHandle &nh, const std::string &topic) {
    sub = nh.subscribe(topic, 1000, &LatchedSubscriber<T>::callback, this);
  }

  T get_last_msg() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(*mutex);
    return *last_received_msg;
  }
};
```

Essentially what it is doing is subscribing to a topic (channel), meaning that a callback function is called each time a message arrives. The job of this class is to store the last received message so the user of the class can always access it.

In the constructor I allocate a shared_ptr to the message and for a mutex to synchronize access to this message. The reason for using heap memory here is so the `LatchedSubscriber` can be copied and the same latched message can still be read. (the `Subscriber` already implements this kind of behavior where copying it doesn't do anything except for the fact that the callback stops being called once the last instance goes out of scope).

The problem is basically that the code segfaults. I am pretty sure the reason for this is that my shared pointers become `null` in the callback function, despite not being null in the constructor.

The `ROS_INFO` calls print:

```
Mutex pointer is not null in constructor
Mutex pointer is null in callback
lrm: pointer is null in callback
Test is 42
```

I don't understand how this can happen. I guess I have either misunderstood something about shared pointers, ros topic subscriptions, or both.

Things I have done:

1. At first I had the subscribe call happening in the constructor. I think giving the `this` pointer to another thread before the constructor has returned can be bad, so I moved this into a `start` function which is called after the object has been constructed.
2. There are many aspects to the thread safety of `shared_ptr`s it seems. At first I used `mutex` and `last_received_msg` directly in the callback. Now I have copied them into local variables hoping this would help. But it doesn't seem to make a difference.
3. I have added a local integer variable. I can read the integer I assigned to this variable in the constructor from the callback. Just a sanity check to make sure that the callback is actually called on an instance created by my constructor.

Comment: I'd like to repro your problem.  Could you make a [mcve] that I can copy-and-paste into a `foo.cpp` file, compile, and see the problem for myself?  I'm pretty sure if I try to write my own code to repro the problem that I won't put in the misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out the problem.

When subscribing I am passing the `this` pointer to the subscribe function along with the callback. If the `LatchedSubscriber` is ever copied and the original deleted, that `this` pointer becomes invalid, but the `sub` still exists so the callback keeps being called.

I didn't think this happened anywhere in my code, but the `LatcedSubscriber` was stored as a member inside an object which was owned by a unique pointer. It looks like `make_unique` might be doing some copying internally? In any case it is wrong to use the `this` pointer for the callback.

I ended up doing the following instead

```
void start(ros::NodeHandle &nh, const std::string &topic) {
    auto l_mutex = mutex;
    auto l_last_received_msg = last_received_msg;

    boost::function<void(const T)> callback =
        [l_mutex, l_last_received_msg](const T msg) {
          std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(*l_mutex);
          *l_last_received_msg = msg;
        };
    sub = nh.subscribe<T>(topic, 1000, callback);
 }
```

This way copies of the two smart pointers are used with the callback instead.

Assigning the closure to a variable of type `boost::function<void(const T)>` seems to be necessary. Probably due to the way the `subscribe` function is.

This appears to have fixed the issue. I might also move the subscription into the constructor again and get rid of the `start` method.